# how do I get a variable from one file to another in php

Tags: php, html

I have 3 files.
I will give you the exact example:

**a.php**

```
<form action="b.php" method="POST">

Enter age:
<input type="text" name="age"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

**b.php**

```
<?php
$age=$_POST["age"];
if (is_numeric($age))
{
    header("Location: c.php");
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Age invalid!";
}
?>
```

**c.php**

```
<?php
//i want to use the $age variable here   
echo $age;
?>
```

How can I use the `$age` variable from `b.php` in `c.php`?

I also tried to session_start(); at file `b.php` and use `$_SESSION["age"]=$_POST["age"];` in `b.php` and then `$_SESSION["age"]` in `c.php` in stead of `$age` and it still didn't work.

I also tried include but didn't get me anywhere either... maybe I didn't use it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that in file b.php, you are not sending the value of age to c.php.

If, in b.php, you did this:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["age"] = $_POST["age"];
```

Then, in c.php, you did this:

```
 session_start();
 $age = $_SESSION["age"];
 echo $age;
```

It will work properly.

Comment: perfect! i am a noob. i didn't use `session_start()` in `c.php`.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When the user submits the form at **a.php**, the browser makes an HTTP POST request to **b.php** *WITH* data.

So you have age in `$_POST`, but your `header()` in **b.php** sends user to **c.php** via HTTP GET request and *that's* why you can't access `$_POST` in **c.php**. This, however, is a good way to prevent refreshing the page causes a data resubmit.

You need to start sessions in **c.php** as well to access session data, using `session_start()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the session you have to call session_start() on every page that you want to use $_SESSION vars, plus session_start() has to come before any output. If you use session_start on both pages, you there's no reason that shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

**b.php:**

```
<?php
   $age=$_POST["age"];
   if (is_numeric($age))
   {
      header("Location: c.php?age=".$age);
      exit();
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Age invalid!";
   }
?>
```

**c.php:**

```
<?php
    //i want to use the $age variable here   
    $age = $_REQUEST["age"];
    echo $age;
?>
```

Comment: What is the point of having b.php validating the input now? Someone can easily use c.php?age=some-text and it will not be validated against is_numeric().

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `session_start()` in **c.php** as well? You have to use `session_start()` in each script that you want to have access to the session. Once you use `session_start()` in **c.php**, you should have access to `$_SESSION['age']`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not modify b.php into ...

```
<?php
$age=$_POST["age"];
if (is_numeric($age))
{
    header("Location: c.php?age=$age"); ### so it will be send as get var
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Age invalid!";
}
?>
```

and in c.php

```
$age = $_GET['age'];
```

or use session as described by cale_b

Comment: that may be so but it's complicated becose I have to send more variables, not just that one. The other answers are more simple. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

you must have to add b.php file into c.php , if you don't want to create a session start and destroy.

than after your c.php file must like this

c.php

```
<?php
include_once 'b.php';
echo $age;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really needed to user `header('location: c.php');`

It doesn't also look to be a right place to user `$_SESSION` variables.

I think you could easily `include 'c.php'` instead of using `header('location: c.php');`.

**b.php**

```
<?php
$age=$_POST["age"];
if (is_numeric($age))
{
    include "c.php"; //THIS LINE HAS BEEN CHANGED
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Age invalid!";
}
?>
```

**c.php**

```
<?php
echo $age; //NO CHANGE AT ALL IN THE FILE 'c.php'
?>
```

So now the browser will stil remain in `localhost/project/b.php` and your internal action that are being performed in `c.php` will stay safe.

`header('location: c.php');` is used to bring user from one page to another. For example after the user logs in or when his session is expired and he should be authenticated again. In this case the user sees that he is being `REDIRECT`ED to unauthorised pages.

**It's not an error** to use `header()` in this case, and the code still works well, but it is not supposed to be for that kind of actions.